# Is it possible to re-arrange widgets based on the project in Sonarqube?

Tags: maven, testing, sonarqube, sonarqube-4.0

I noticed that existence and placements of widgets are global across all projects in Sonar. Is it possible to customize based on project? For example, if I want project A to have only 1 widget and 1-frame layout, while project B is divided into a 3-column layout with 10 different widgets, is it possible to do so?

The reason I ask is because from an overview perspective we use the "measure filter as treemap" widget in the home dashboard to give a visual overview of all projects based on a certain metric. However, if we don't want to include a certain project even though it has the metric (It is a branch of another project), we can't do so.

From a customization POV, some widgets are simply not needed in certain projects even if they show anything.

I've tried going through the documentation and of course google/SO search but have not found anything related to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you try to achieve is not possible currently. The dashboards are always displayed the same way, whatever the project.